# Как обойти это ограничение: Mixins may not be defined within control directives or other mixins? (Webpack)

Tags: webpack, sass, scss, node-sass

Столкнулся с тем, что нужно реализовать доступ к миксинам по условию в **scss**.
Но столкнулся с этой ошибкой когда запустил сборку -

**Mixins may not be defined within control directives or other mixins**

Как обойти это ограничение ?

Пример кода

```
$list: (sw: true, a: false, b: false, c: false);

$retun: map-get($list, sw);

@if ($retun == true){
  @mixin r2{
    color: firebrick;
  };
}
```

Использую **webpack** *v4.26.0*

пакеты к нему

```
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
```

Конфиг

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'ready.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('./css/style.css')
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько это хорошая практика, но можно попробовать воспользоваться -

**наследованием классов**

Так он не ругается и можно сделать вот такие конструкции:)

```
$list: (sw: true, a: false, b: false, c: false);

$retun: map-get($list, sw);


%mix1 {
  @mixin r2($ix){
    @if ($ix == 1) {
      color: #b22222;
    } @else {
      color: salmon;
    }
  };
  @if ($retun == true) {
    @include r2(0);
  } @else {
    @include r2(1);
  }

}

.text{
 @extend %mix1;
}
```